# Is an array considered as boolean true in php?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I have a quick question here. I know that the [cakePHP find('first')](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1019/find-first) function returns an array containing the first result if found, false otherwise. My question is this, what if I were to write a check like this:

```
if(result_is_array) // that means I have data
{
    // do something
}
else // that means result is a boolean
{
    // do something else
}
```

Instead of checking whether the result obtained from `find('first')` is an array or not, can I just say:

```
$result = $this->MyModel->find('first');
if($result)
{
    // do something
}
```

In order words, if I get an array here, will that evaluate to `TRUE` in php? Is `if(array())` equal to `true` in php?

Comment: Why not just test it instead of spending all that time to post a question? `var_dump((bool) array());`

Comment: This isn't cakePHP specific, please tag questions correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YES, you can do

```
$result = $this->MyModel->find('first');
if($result)
```

An array with `length > 0` returns `true`

[Explanation is here in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE
>
> - an array with zero elements
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE

Answer (score 2):

A zero value array is `false`

An array with values in it is `true`

You can view [this table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to see what is evaluated as `true` vs `false`.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of checking whether the result obtained from find('first') is
>   an array or not

Yes. Do it the second way:`if ($result)`. If `find` returns an empty array or boolean `false`, the branch will not be executed.

The best part about doing it this way is that **it makes it clear to the reader that you are checking for a *non-empty* value.**

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), if you try to treat an array as a boolean, the array will be considered true precisely when it's not empty.

Comment: Nitpick: if you try to *treat* an array as a boolean.  If you pass it somewhere, you're still passing an array, even if the callee wanted a bool.

Answer (score 0):

An empty array will always evaluate to false or if it contain any key/values then it will evaluate to true. if `$this->MyModel->find('first');` always returns an array then an empty result will evaluate to false and true other wise. so your code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if you are looking for a `TRUE` value:

```
if ( $result !== false )
{
    // do something
}
```